# How to save file details into DB in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to insert the details of an uploaded file into a database table and I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo::getClientOriginalName()

How would I get the `getClientOriginalName()`, `getClientOriginalName()` and  `getFilename()` of a file in Laravel5?

Below is the code I am using.

```
public function add() 
{
  $directory = public_path('xml');

  $files = File::allFiles($directory);
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $entry = new Xmlentry();
    $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
    $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $entry->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;
    $entry->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: What does dd($files) output?

Comment: It prints `array:1 [
  0 => SplFileInfo {#164
    -relativePath: ""
    -relativePathname: "145629930664170.xml"
  }`

Comment: I think the issue is that those methods are part of `UploadedFile` class, not `SplFileInfo`. But, you can convert one into the other using something like this: `new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile($files[0]->getFilename(),$files[0]->getPath());`

Comment: How can I put this in my code above if I had thousands of files in the directory?

Comment: I put my response as an answer as it was too messy for a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused why you have `getClientOriginalName()` in there because that's aimed at temporary file names that have been uploaded but `File::allFiles()` is getting files from a directory that already have fixed names.

In addition to my comments above, I wanted to add you can just use the `SplFileInfo` methods.

I've taken the liberty of removing original file name from the code and correcting the lack of assignment statement for the variable `$extension`.

To answer your question:

```
public function add() 
{
  $directory = public_path('xml');

  $files = File::allFiles($directory);
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $entry = new Xmlentry();
    $entry->mime = $file->getType();
    $entry->filename = $file->getFilename(). '.' . $file->getExtension();
    $entry->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. You simply the best.

Comment: Glad I could help :)